# Run php script every 3 seconds

Tags: debian, cron

how can I set a **cron job** or a php script details to run a php script **every 3 seconds** between 11:30 PM and 12:30 AM (23:30 - 0:30)?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't; `cron` doesn't offer per-second granularity.

If you must do this, it may be simplest to write a script that ends with a three second delay, then loops back to the beginning as long as the time is between 2330 and 0030, and invoke it once from `cron` at 2330.

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way, feel free to accept one of the answers to this question - and you should probably review some of your other open questions, while you're at it.

Comment: Thanx again. I still learn to know this website.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with cron since the most frequent a cronjob can run is every minute.

You are better off writing the script to run continuously with a loop and perform the work every 3 seconds.

Comment: Since you are venturing into the land of developing a daemon, you will need to make sure you tighten up your script a lot.  Make sure you properly `unset()` and properly close any resources you are not using.